# Ambiguous reference for IdentityUser

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm implementing authentication in -net Core 2 api and I've found this error after this code:

StartUp.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

MyContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class MyContext: IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> opt)
        : base(opt) { }

    public DbSet<Room> Rooms{ get; set; }
}
```

Error in MyCOntext.cs:

```
'IdentityUser' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUser' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'
```

Thank you all.

Comment: remove using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity; in MyContext.cs

Answer (score 0):

Since `IdentityUser` exists in both of the mentioned namespaces, you need to either remove one of them or explicitly specify which one to use by a `using` like the following:

```
using IdentityUser = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUser
```

Comment: Hi Rad, If I do that I get the error:  The type ApplicationUser cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'IdentityDbContext<TUser>' Thanks for your help

Comment: I think it's a new error and not related to the previous one. Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788816/the-type-applicationuser-cannot-be-used-as-type-parameter-tuser-in-the-generic

Comment: I think that the main problem is that I have startup and context in different projects and when I try to install identity.EntityFrameworkCore via nugget I get the error:      Downgrade of a package detected : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore de 2.2.0 a 1.1.6. 
 WebAPI -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0) 
 WebAPI -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 1.1.6)

Comment: To Install in the main project I mean

Answer (score 0):

#### This may help

This problem occurs to me, in my case I found the problem occurs
because of old NuGet package

I installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore : v 1.1.0`

But current version is `3.1.4`, so i just update it and everything works.